# Python VISSIM COM interface - Vissim.Net.Vehicles.GetMultipleAttributes("'EmissionsCO2'") returns None

Tags: python, com, traffic-simulation

I'm trying to measure the emissions and fuel consumption of all my vehicles in the network. I'm running some simulations with AVs and human driven vehicles (HDVs). I'm running python 3.7.6 and I interface with VISSIM using COM API.

Basically, I create X number of HDVs in a loop using:

```
for i in range(x):
    hdvs.append(Vissim.Net.Vehicles.AddVehicleAtLinkPosition( 100, link, lane, pos, desired_speed, interaction))
```

Then I control my AVs and in the end try to access the vehicles emissions, fuel consumption and total travel distance:

```
all_veh_emissions = Vissim.Net.Vehicles.GetMultipleAttributes(('EmissionsCO2', 'EmissionsNOx', 'FuelConsumption', 'DistTravTotal'))
```

EmissionCO2, EmissionsNOx and FuelConsumption returns None, and DistTravTotal returns the true number in meters. So, why can I not access the emissions and fuel consumption numbers? Have I missed something in VISSIM?

Best regards,
Jacob

Answer (score 0):

To get emissions and fuel consumption of each vehicle, extra add-on module is required.

According to Vissim manual pdf file,

> If you have purchased the add-on module **API**, you can access the *Emission Model.dll* file for emission calculation via an interface. You must provide the *EmissionModel.dll*. It is not part of Vissim.

p.s. Mine is Vissim 11.00.